# elasticSearch filters not beeing applied?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm using elasticSearch to find the next episode in a series. I do this by first filtering for episodes that has either a higher `season` OR a higher `episode` than the previous episode, then sorting on `season` and `episode` in ascending order, and limit my results to 1:

```
    ...            
        FilterBuilder sameSeriesFilter = termsFilter("tvShowId", previousEpisode.getTvShowId());
        FilterBuilder greaterEpisodeFilter = rangeFilter("episode").gt(previousEpisode.getEpisode());
        FilterBuilder greaterSeasonFilter = rangeFilter("season").gt(previousEpisode.getSeason());
        List<Sort.Field> sortFields = Arrays.asList(new Sort.Field("season", Sort.Order.ASC),new Sort.Field("episode", Sort.Order.ASC));
        Sort episodeSort = new Sort(sortFields);


        AndFilterBuilder filter = FilterBuilders.andFilter(
                sameSeriesFilter,
                orFilter(
                        greaterEpisodeFilter,
                        greaterSeasonFilter
                )
        );

        String query = filter.toString(); //here for debugging purposes

        return client.getItems(GetItems
            .<Asset>newBuilder()
                .index(index)
                .filter(filter)
                .sort(episodeSort)
                .page(1,1)
                .type(ASSET)
                .tClass(Asset.class)
                .build()
        );
    }).map(assetHitList ->
            assetHitList.getHits().isEmpty() ? null : assetHitList.getHits().get(0)) ;
}
```

extracting the filters as a string at runtime gives me the following query:

```
    {
  "and" : {
    "filters" : [ {
      "terms" : {
        "tvShowId" : [ "breaking-bad" ]
      }
    },{
      "or" : {
        "filters" : [ {
          "range" : {
            "episode" : {
              "from" : 1,
              "to" : null,
              "include_lower" : false,
              "include_upper" : true
            }
          }
        }, {
          "range" : {
            "season" : {
              "from" : 2,
              "to" : null,
              "include_lower" : false,
              "include_upper" : true
            }
          }
        } ]
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

which confusingly results in:

```
{
  "assetId" : "breaking-bad-s01-e1_foobar",
  "tvShowId" : "breaking-bad"
  "episode" : "1",
  "season" : "1",
  "originalTitle" : "Dummy breaking-bad-s01-e1_foobar",
}
```

(some fields were removed for brevity)

note that `episode` and `season` in the result are both 1, even though the filters specifies (I thought) one of them has to be higher than 2 and 1 respectively.

I also tried to invert the sorting, and sort descending instead, and that resulted in a episode from a completely different series, so it seems the `sameSeriesFilter` isn't being applied either, however sorting seems to work!

anyway...Whats going on here?

Update:
Forgot to mention, this is v.1.7 of ES.

I've managed to get it working, but something mysterious is going on.
On a whim I added a empty matchAll query, which should do nothing, but for some reason makes everything work. my filters are now applied correctly. Is ES supposed to work like this? if so, why?
the new and working code:

```
     return client.getItems(GetItems
            .<Asset>newBuilder()
                .index(index)
                .matchAllQuery()  //<--this made it work!?!
                .filter(filter)
                .sort(episodeSort)
                .page(1,1)
                .type(ASSET)
                .tClass(Asset.class)
                .build()
        );
```

Comment: What happens if you run your JSON query directly with curl or in Sense?

Comment: Hi Val! You're probably on to something, i didn't yet try to curl it, but I speculate, from what I added in my update, the query I logged probably never made it to the database, for some mysterious reason. I got it working now so less of an emergency, but I'd still like to understand what's happening, any clues?

Comment: I would like to see the whole query, not only the filters.